# How to redirect all my routes to www in my laravel in local and live both

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

I have a laravel app . when I dd($request->url()) the any request it shows me url like this 
http://example.test in screen but what I want is I want to get http://www.example.test

I have tried fews things like changing in .htaccess file and using middleware

I have done this in my middleware

```
if (starts_with($request->header('host'), 'www.')) {
            $host = str_replace('www.', '', $request->header('host'));
            $request->headers->set('host', $host);

            return Redirect::to($request->fullUrl(), 301);
        }

        return $next($request);
```

But still nothing happend and in my htaccess file I did this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

But still the same . I want to know if thats because I am using homestead or My code is worong 
Note: I want to see it on localhost too and I am using vagrant homestead laravel

Answer (score 0):

Try in web.php file

```
$req_path = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/");
if (strpos($req_path,"www") ==false){
 $req_path = trim($req_path,"/");
 $url = "http://www.example.test/".$req_path;
 header("location:".$url, true,301);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can try use [this](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-url) in your case